# Receiving UNKNOWN ERROR: read error on connection to ec2-34-194-152-137.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6379 when executing SOQL in workbench

Tags: workbench

I am encountering the below error when trying to execute SOQL in workbench. I am am getting the same error using API v56 or API v57 on different salesforce orgs as well. I have not changed anything on my system recently

UNKNOWN ERROR: read error on connection to ec2-34-194-152-137.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6379